# Multiple Connections to Web Server ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have an ASP.NET web service that I am hosting on IIS 6 (may change to IIS 7 in the future). The .asmx page may receive many requests at the same time. It takes approximately 3s per request per CPU to return a response after a request is received (so two requests will also come back in 3s on a dual-core). However, when multiple requests come in at once (or close enough), the service seems to try to make it look like it is processing all of them at the same time. For example, if 6 requests come in, they all return in around 9s instead of the first two coming back in 3s, the next 2 in 6s, and the final 2 in 9s. My questions are: What is going on (briefly or elaborately if you have the patience :)), and how can I limit the number of requests or threads created from the service point-of-view, preferably without making any changes to IIS or machine.config?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Just to clarify, I'm trying to make the web service perform as 1st in 1st out sort of situation, where the first n requests are processed (n = number of processors), then the next ones. Right now, if I send 10 requests at once, the service gathers all of them together and splits the processing up among all processors. It seems to me that in theory, if I can tell the service to limit the number of simultaneous processing to n (corresponding to the # of processors), then I will achieve my goal. But I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Are all these 9 requests come from the same client\session or it's from different clients?

Comment: Same client during testing, but there may be multiple clients upon release.

Comment: If your web service uses ASP.Net session(have such attribute `[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]`), then by default Session Provider uses locking for the same client. So at the moment only one request from the same client will be processed. All other requests will be queued until first request frees Session.

Comment: I do have session enabled. but multiple requests DO seem to be processed from the same client because they are all being done at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

In [Pro ASP.NET Web API: HTTP Web Services in ASP.NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430247258) book -

> With .NET Framework 4.0, the default configuration settings are
>   suitable for most scenarios. For example, in ASP.NET 4.0 and 4.5, the
>   MaxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU value is set to 5000 by default (it had
>   been a very low number in earlier versions of .NET). According to team
>   members of IIS, there’s nothing special about the value 5000. It was
>   set because it is a very large number and will allow plenty of async
>   requests to execute concurrently. **This setting should be fine, so
>   there is no need to change it.**
>
> ***Tip***  Windows 7, Windows Vista, and all other Windows client operating
>   systems handle a maximum of 10 concurrent requests. You need to have a
>   Windows Server operating system or use IIS Express to see the benefits
>   of asynchronous methods under high load.

Comment: I am actually using .net 3.5. But how can I reduce the max concurrent requests from the service point-of-view (not iis/asp.net system-wide)?

Comment: By default, .Net 3.5 is [12 requests per CPU](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/07/21/asp-net-thread-usage-on-iis-7-0-and-6-0.aspx). I don't think you want to set lower than that, because it is low enough already. I don't know how to advise you without seeing your code. Could you profile your code (with both performance profiler and memory profile) and see what make your code slowing down?

Comment: How can I change it though?

Comment: [IIS7 – Improving ASP.NET performance (concurrent requests) while on Integrated Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2009/07/08/iis7-improving-asp-net-performance-concurrent-requests-while-on-integrated-mode.aspx) I couldn't find the solution for IIS 6.